# Create 2 endpoints or methods based on the same model - django restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Trying django rest framework, is possible to have 2 endpoints returning different data based on the same model?
I need something like this.

api/tarjetas should return all the objects created while api/tarjetasusuario should return objects created by an specific user.

Thanks

```html
class TarjetaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tarjeta.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TarjetaSerializer
    permission_classes = (OwnerPermission,)


class TarjetasusuarioViewSet(APIView):
    queryset = Tarjeta.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TarjetaSerializer
    permission_classes = (OwnerPermission,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Tarjeta.objects.filter(usuario=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Why bother writing two views?? You could write a single viewset and filter using a GET parameter...!

Comment: This code seems right to me. Any error you are getting ?

Comment: no errors, but I'm getting the same data on both. maybe the problem is on the router? any ideas?


`code`
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'tarjetas', TarjetaViewSet)
router.register(r'tarjetasusuario', TarjetasusuarioViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
`code`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this reference

```
class TarjetaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Tarjeta.objects.all()
   serializer_class = TarjetaSerializer
   permission_classes = (OwnerPermission,)


class TarjetasusuarioViewSet(APIView):
   user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
   queryset = Tarjeta.objects.filter(usuario=user)
   serializer_class = TarjetaSerializer
   permission_classes = (OwnerPermission,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must extend from ModelViewSet in TarjetasusuarioViewSet class:

```
class TarjetaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tarjeta.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TarjetaSerializer
    permission_classes = (OwnerPermission,)


class TarjetasusuarioViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tarjeta.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TarjetaSerializer
    permission_classes = (OwnerPermission,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Tarjeta.objects.filter(usuario=self.request.user)
```